# Adding OAuth to a rest api for testing

Tags: rest, api, oauth-2.0, uber-api, web-api-testing

So I am testing the  REST API's given by uber to implement uber service into my app, while sending a request to one of their api it sends me response massage:

```
{
    "message": "No authentication provided.",
    "code": "unauthorized"
}
```

while iam doing the same request as given in their [doc](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/me-get)

the request iam creating:
headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>
Accept-Language: en_US
Content-Type: application/json
```

to url `https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me`

where iam getting wrong and what else do I need to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to use any Uber API endpoint, you will need to authorize your user and get access_token. From your sample code we can see that you did not follow the instructions on Uber documentation. So to make sure you are following full authentication process like it supposes to be please find below info:

The Authorization Code flow is a two-step authorization process. The first step is having the user authorize your app and the second involves requesting an OAuth 2.0 access token from Uber. This process is mandatory if you want to take actions on behalf of a user or access their information. 
The redirect URL "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI" is the URL we will redirect back to after an authorization by the resource owner. The base of the URI must match the redirect_uri used during the registration of your application. If none is provided the default is the first redirect URI provided in the application's dashboard

"YOUR_LIST_OF_SCOPES" is the list of scopes you have requested in the authorizations tab. Based what you want to achieve and what API calls you want to make - you will need the certain scope to be used in your two-step authorization process. You can use multiple scopes as comma delimited list.

Please follow the steps of the authentication guide.

Briefly, you need to:

• Send user to authorize url. It starts by redirecting the user to the authorize endpoint: https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&scope=YOUR_LIST_OF_SCOPES .

• Receive the redirect with an authorization code. After the user approves the scopes the user will be redirected to the redirect_uri with an auth code that you can post to the /v2/token endpoint to receive an access token.

• Make a POST call to: 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token'. This call will return access_token and refresh_token.

• After you get your access_token you can use it in the API's endpoints